# Can't build Angular library with SASS mixin from node modules

Tags: angular, sass, angular-library, ng-packagr

**Setup:** Angular 9 workspace with libraries, a test app and storybook using CDK's `_overlay.scss` in a `.scss` file with `@use`.

```
.storybook/
node_modules/
projects/
- library/
  - src/
    - lib/
      - component/
        component.scss // `@use`s `_overlay.scss`
  ng-package.json
- test-app/
angular.json
```

**Issue:** When using the overlay sass mixin `@use "~@angular/cdk/overlay"` the test app and storybook compile but ng-packagr can't find `_overlay.scss`.

```
ERROR: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
2 │ @use "~@angular/cdk/overlay";
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  projects\library\src\lib\component\component.scss 2:1  root stylesheet
An unhandled exception occurred: Can't find stylesheet to import.
```

Workarounds:

- It's possible to add `node_modules/` to `ng-package.json`'s `"styleIncludePaths": "["../../node_modules"]"` array and import the overlay mixin like `@use "@angular/cdk/overlay"` but then it doesn't work with the test app or storybook; also, the IDE can't resolve the path.
- `@use "overlay"`, `"styleIncludePaths": ["../../node_modules/@angular/cdk"]` and `"stylePreprocessorOptions": {"includePaths": ["node_modules/@angular/cdk"]}` works for the test app and library build but not for storybook; also, the IDE can't resolve the path. Maybe storybook can be configured to work with this setup.
- Changing the path to `@use "../../../../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay"` works during development but would fail in production when someone tries to add the library to their node_modules and `@use` the mixin.
- Copying `_overlay.scss` into the library would work but it would need to be updated with every cdk change.
- Providing a custom webpack.config could possibly work but it would need to be updated if angular changes under the hood.

**Q:** Shouldn't the import with tilde `~` actually work if `"styleIncludePaths": ["../../node_modules/"]` is set in `ng-package.json`? Is this an issue with ng-packagr?